# Non-empty string as route parameter

Tags: 8, routes, search

I'm creating a search results page using the Search API. I want to set an url like this:

```
    /search/{text}
```

How should i set up my route? It must accept any combination of characters, including non-ascii, spaces, numbers, etc, but it must not be empty.

This is my current routing rule. As you can see, there is no restriction for the text parameter:

```
    my.search.results:
      path: '/search/{text}'
      defaults:
        text: NULL
        _controller: '\Drupal\my\Controller\SearchController::results'
        _title: 'Search Results'
      requirements:
        _permission: 'access content'
```

Comment: I think you might want to set text to `\w+`, but I am not 100% certain. See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/requirements.html Plus, it should go under requirements.

Comment: Symfony placeholders are required unless told otherwise - just remove the default value?

Comment: \w+ will fail if there is a space (%20) between words. Removing the default value will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As long as a default value isn't provided in the route definition, every route placeholder is required. Defining the route as follow is sufficient.

```yaml
my.search.results:
  path: '/search/{text}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my\Controller\SearchController::results'
    _title: 'Search Results'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content
```

See, for example, the definition of the *dblog.event* route in the [dblog.routing.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21dblog%21dblog.routing.yml/8.9.x) file.

```yaml
dblog.event:
  path: '/admin/reports/dblog/event/{event_id}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\dblog\Controller\DbLogController::eventDetails'
    _title: 'Details'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access site reports'
```

The controller associated to that route, [`DbLogController::eventDetails()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21dblog%21src%21Controller%21DbLogController.php/function/DbLogController%3A%3AeventDetails/8.9.x), doesn't check the value of `$event_id` is an empty string, simply because it won't get an empty string for that parameter.

```php
public function eventDetails($event_id) {
  $dblog = $this->database->query('SELECT w.*, u.uid FROM {watchdog} w LEFT JOIN {users} u ON u.uid = w.uid WHERE w.wid = :id', [
    ':id' => $event_id,
  ])
    ->fetchObject();
  if (empty($dblog)) {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
  }
  // …
}
```